# A 'secure' reference network diagram

Tags: network

Recently, I have found out about [Microsoft Cybersecurity Reference Architecture](https://www.microsoft.com/security/blog/2018/06/06/cybersecurity-reference-architecture-security-for-a-hybrid-enterprise/). It shows how Microsoft products can fit into an existing company's network and policy setup, however it is quite generic.

I am looking for something similar to that, but just an example, reference network diagram from a known tech company or mentioned in a scientific paper, such as the "logical diagram" on the left hand side of the image below. Previously, I have come across "[An analysis of cyber reference architectures](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiroMzu-p3tAhX3aRUIHe3PCPsQFjAAegQIBhAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.sto.nato.int%2Fpublications%2FSTO%2520Educational%2520Notes%2FSTO-EN-IST-143%2FEN-IST-143-09.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1bw6FxPWfKzXEWXrwpiFqS)", but again, the diagrams mostly feature lists of things (policies, security awareness, physical and non-physical measures etc.), as opposed to those lists applied to an example diagram.

[image: Two network diagram examples. Left one shows an abstracted view with titles such as Remote office 1, Firewall, Webserver; the one on the right shows a physical diagram - actual ip addresses, routers and overall is on a lower level of abstraction.]

**In short:** Are there any example/use case/reference 'secure' network diagrams, such as the one on the left above, that have been released from a well-known source?

**EDIT:** All of the answers are great, thank you for taking the time to answer! I am struggling to accept one because they both provide really good perspective on the matter.

Answer (score 3):

There are two reasons you are unlikely to find an actual diagram with the info you want

- It is the sort of thing that an attacker would love to have, making navigation through their target's network simple and stealthy
- It will only be relevant to that organisation. You will need to tailor the architecture to your needs, not that of another company.

The reference diagrams are a really useful place to start from, just make sure you get input from your business heads as well as technology leads, so you know what services and data need to be protected, and these will guide your customisation of the network controls.

Comment: That is a very good point, thank you for mentioning it. While in my case it is just reserach, I would guess that for every 'sample' network out there there will be people who will copy it verbatim, putting themselves and their organisation at a security risk.

Answer (score -1):

modern answer is zero-trust network security, where each and every network web or API endpoint is individually protected by an identity-aware proxy.

that was pioneered by Google's Beyond Corp network security model, and has been adopted by numerous vendors.

- [Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/beyondcorp-enterprise)
- [Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/teams/access)
- [Pomerium (open source)](https://pomerium.io) - if you need full control
- [managed service for internal apps](https://gw.run/) - managed service that is simple, requires zero setup and lets you securely expose apps behind firewall or running inside containers

Comment: Thank you for linking this up! I needed zero trust to be brought to my attention, because it is one of the things I was looking for!